# ¿Cómo llenar los controles de mi Form desde un DataGridView que se alimenta con una sentencia SQL? C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, vb.net

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en **C#** que al hacer doble click en un registro (o fila) de mi **DataGridView** llene los datos seleccionado en los controles de mi formulario (ComboBox, TextBox, NumericUpDown).

El problema está en que no logro realizar esa acción. Este mismo trabajo lo he hecho en VB.NET pero con C# no logro conseguir lo mismo. La base de datos que uso es SqlServer.

A continuación les dejo mi línea de código hecho en VB.NET como ejemplo para ver si se puede aplicar la misma lógica pero en C#:

```
 Private Sub dgvDatos_CellDoubleClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgvDatos.CellDoubleClick

        'Evento que se dispara cuando se hace doble clic en alguna celda del DataGridView

        Try

            'Creamos un sqlCommand y al momento de instanciarlo ya configuramos el CommandText y la conexión

            Dim vComando As New SqlCommand("select * from Articulo where ArticuloId = " & dgvDatos(0, e.RowIndex).Value, vConexion)
            'Creamos e instanciamos un objeto DataTable
            Dim dtConsulta As New DataTable
            'Creamos e instanciamos un Adaptador
            Dim adaptadorConsulta As New SqlDataAdapter(vComando)
            'Ejecutamos la consulta en la bd y el resultado lo volcamos al objeto DataTable
            adaptadorConsulta.Fill(dtConsulta)

            'Si después de realizar la consulta el DataTable cuenta con Registros o filas mostramos el contenido de cada campo en el control correspondiente
            'Rows(0): Primera fila del DataTable.
            'Item("xxxx"): Especificamos el nombre de la columna que queremos recuperar
            If dtConsulta.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                txtCodigo.Text = dtConsulta.Rows(0).Item("ArticuloId")
                txtDescripcion.Text = dtConsulta.Rows(0).Item("Descripcion")
                nudPrecioVenta.Value = dtConsulta.Rows(0).Item("PrecioVenta")
                nudPrecioCompra.Value = dtConsulta.Rows(0).Item("PrecioCompra")
                cboProveedor.SelectedValue = dtConsulta.Rows(0).Item("ProveedorId")
                nudExistenciaMaxima.Value = dtConsulta.Rows(0).Item("ExistenciaMaxima")
                nudExistenciaMinima.Value = dtConsulta.Rows(0).Item("ExistenciaMinima")
                nudExistencia.Value = dtConsulta.Rows(0).Item("Existencia")
                cboTipoImpuesto.SelectedValue = dtConsulta.Rows(0).Item("TipoImpuestoId")
                cboUnidadMedida.SelectedValue = dtConsulta.Rows(0).Item("UnidadMedidaId")

                'Pasamos a la primera pestaña (Mantenimiento)
                tbcABM.SelectedIndex = 0
                'Bajamos la bandera de Nuevo Registro
                vNuevo = False
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Comment: Basicamente, ¿la pregunta es para pedir que te conviertan el código a C#? Porque ambos lenguajes usan las mismas librerías y funcionan igual. Es solo cuestión de pasar la sintaxis de uno al del otro. No me parece una pregunta adecuada para este sitio.

Comment: Sí, ambos lenguajes trabajan en el mismo Framework. De cualquier forma... necesito saber cómo hacerlo en C#, viéndolo desde ese lado no sé cómo pasar de una sintaxis a otra. Gracias, saludos.

Comment: Si vas a estar escribiendo código en C#, toma el tiempo de aprender su sintaxis. De nada sirve que te convirtamos código, si después no sabrás como modificarlo y escribir más código. Si no, vas a estar preguntando que te traduzcamos código constantemente, y este sitio no es para eso de todas maneras.

Comment: Te dejo esta página: http://converter.telerik.com/ te puede ayudar a convertir el código, aunque eso si, no lo hace al 100% por culpa de cómo maneja cada lenguaje algunas cosas, por ejemplo, en VB los índices son con paréntesis: "lista(0).valor = xxx;" y en c# los paréntesis son para métodos (funciones) y para los índices se usan los []: "lista[0].valor = xxx", así que si tienes índices en tu código, el convertidor los pasará como si fuesen funciones.

Comment: @sstan Gracias por tus aclaraciones, busqué mucho la forma de cómo hacerlo en C# pero no me resultó.

Comment: Perfecto @Luis voy a darle un vistazo...

Comment: @julioAgustin estoy de acuerdo con lo comentado por sstan, es mejor que estudies la sintaxis de C# revisa este link http://www.mundoprogramacion.com/NET/revistas/dotNetmania/pdf/dotnetmania_1_2_3.pdf puedes ayudarte con infinidad de convertidores de código que hay en la web, por otro lado te recomendaría que aprendas a trabajar en capas http://joseluisgarciab.blogspot.com/2014/09/programacion-en-3-capas.html te permite reutilizar código, separar responsabilidades, tener mas limpio y ordenado tu código, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Te dejo el código convertido en c# usando http://converter.telerik.com/ . Únicamente le cambié algunas cosas como los () por [] en los índices, ya que el convertidor no los convierte bien:

```
private void dgvDatos_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    //Evento que se dispara cuando se hace doble clic en alguna celda del DataGridView


    try {
        //Creamos un sqlCommand y al momento de instanciarlo ya configuramos el CommandText y la conexión

        SqlCommand vComando = new SqlCommand("select * from Articulo where ArticuloId = " + dgvDatos[0, e.RowIndex].Value, vConexion);
        //Creamos e instanciamos un objeto DataTable
        DataTable dtConsulta = new DataTable();
        //Creamos e instanciamos un Adaptador
        SqlDataAdapter adaptadorConsulta = new SqlDataAdapter(vComando);
        //Ejecutamos la consulta en la bd y el resultado lo volcamos al objeto DataTable
        adaptadorConsulta.Fill(dtConsulta);

        //Si después de realizar la consulta el DataTable cuenta con Registros o filas mostramos el contenido de cada campo en el control correspondiente
        //Rows[0]: Primera fila del DataTable.
        //Item["xxxx"]: Especificamos el nombre de la columna que queremos recuperar
        if (dtConsulta.Rows.Count > 0) {
            txtCodigo.Text = dtConsulta.Rows[0].Item["ArticuloId"];
            txtDescripcion.Text = dtConsulta.Rows[0].Item["Descripcion"];
            nudPrecioVenta.Value = dtConsulta.Rows[0].Item["PrecioVenta"];
            nudPrecioCompra.Value = dtConsulta.Rows[0].Item["PrecioCompra"];
            cboProveedor.SelectedValue = dtConsulta.Rows[0].Item["ProveedorId"];
            nudExistenciaMaxima.Value = dtConsulta.Rows[0].Item["ExistenciaMaxima"];
            nudExistenciaMinima.Value = dtConsulta.Rows[0].Item["ExistenciaMinima"];
            nudExistencia.Value = dtConsulta.Rows[0].Item["Existencia"];
            cboTipoImpuesto.SelectedValue = dtConsulta.Rows[0].Item["TipoImpuestoId"];
            cboUnidadMedida.SelectedValue = dtConsulta.Rows[0].Item["UnidadMedidaId"];

            //Pasamos a la primera pestaña (Mantenimiento)
            tbcABM.SelectedIndex = 0;
            //Bajamos la bandera de Nuevo Registro
            vNuevo = false;
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Esto te puede servir de guía para que puedas pasar mas código de vb.net a c#.

**EDIT:** Toma en cuenta que c# es un lenguaje fuertemente tipeado (o como se traduzca strongly typed), lo que quiere decir que te va a marcar error si intentas hacer cosas como "string numero = 9", que es permitido en vb.net si no usas la directiva "Option Strict On". Lo digo por si tienes código de ese tipo, muy común en proyectos vb.net.